# I try to create filter number

Tags: google-apps-script

I try to create filter number: the value of textBox filter accept only number.
 you can help me please 
The filter accepts a int or  fload not int var

`function callok(e){
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
var montantEE = e.parametre.MontantEE;
if (montantEE==number){app.getElementById('validateLabel').setText('PleaseMontant !');
}else{
app.getElementById('validateLabel').setText('You entered: '+ e.parametre.MontantEE);
return app;`

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure I understood precisely your requirements but I'd suggest you use a validator coupled with a clientHandler to achieve what you need.

Simply add a [integer-validator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/ui/client-handler#validateInteger(Widget)) to a clientHandler that will enable the button you probably use to submit the values. Use an nonInteger validator to ensure that any typing correction is handled as well.

Here is an example code and a [test app online](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxB8CW_LBUN7EpXQGZ5yLIfnxjjhhr-jkaiPsVlEdjRft69WEGR/exec)

```
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('test sidebar');
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var btn = app.createButton('submit').setEnabled(false);
  var inputBox = app.createTextBox().setName('num');
  var cHandler1 = app.createClientHandler().validateInteger(inputBox).forTargets(btn).setEnabled(true).forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor','lightgreen');
  var cHandler2 = app.createClientHandler().validateNotInteger(inputBox).forTargets(btn).setEnabled(false).forEventSource().setStyleAttribute('backgroundColor','red');
  inputBox.addKeyUpHandler(cHandler1).addKeyUpHandler(cHandler2);
  panel.add(inputBox).add(btn);
  return app.add(panel);
```